# SSRS BIDS 2008 Parameter drop down visible on report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, bids

See attached, circled image.

In BIDS when i preview this report, the parameters drop down menu is visible straight away, however when i deploy it to the server and run the report, i have to click the circled button to show the parameter options.

This may be easily missed by the user, is it possible to set this to appear by default?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the report parameters are configured to be hidden. In Business Intelligence Development Studio:

- open the Report Data tab -> Parameters
- right-click each of the parameters -> Parameter Properties
- **make sure *Select parameter visbility* is set to *Visible*.**

Parameter selection for all my reports are shown by default unless this is checked.

If you're linking the report from another page (or from another report), add **`&rc:Parameters=true`** to the URL. Info on additional URL parameters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx).